# Reading a single-key input on Linux (without waiting for return) using x86_64 sys_call

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, tty

I want to make Linux just take 1 keystroke from keyboard using sys_read, but sys_read just wait until i pressed enter. How to read 1 keystroke ? this is my code:

```
Mov EAX,3
Mov EBX,0
Mov ECX,Nada
Mov EDX,1
Int 80h

Cmp ECX,49
Je Do_C
Jmp Error
```

I already tried using BIOS interrupt but it's failed (Segmentation fault), I want capture number 1 to 8 input from keyboard.

Comment: The problem is that the terminal by default is in "cooked" mode, which is line buffered, while to get single keystrokes you need it in raw mode; see e.g. https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html; BTW BIOS interrupt don't work when you are running under an OS (especially in protected mode).

Comment: You can't use `int 80h` in 64-bit assembly

Comment: @JCWasmx86 You can, but the results are [usually wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730/417501).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Syscalls in 64-bit linux

The tables from `man syscall` provide a good overview here:

```
arch/ABI   instruction          syscall #   retval Notes
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
i386       int $0x80            eax         eax
x86_64     syscall              rax         rax    See below

arch/ABI      arg1  arg2  arg3  arg4  arg5  arg6  arg7  Notes
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
i386          ebx   ecx   edx   esi   edi   ebp   -
x86_64        rdi   rsi   rdx   r10   r8    r9    -
```

I have omitted the lines that are not relevant here. In 32-bit mode, the parameters were transferred in `ebx`, `ecx`, etc and the syscall number is in `eax`. In 64-bit mode it is a little different: All registers are now 64-bit wide and therefore have a different name. The syscall number is still in `eax`, which now becomes `rax`. But the parameters are now passed in `rdi`, `rsi`, etc. In addition, the instruction `syscall` is used here instead of `int 0x80` to trigger a syscall.

The order of the parameters can also be read in the man pages, here `man 2 ioctl` and `man 2 read`:

```
int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long request, ...);
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

So here the value of `int fd` is in `rdi`, the second parameter in `rsi` etc.

### How to get rid of waiting for a newline

Firstly create a `termios` structure in memory (in `.bss` section):

```
termios:
  c_iflag resd 1   ; input mode flags
  c_oflag resd 1   ; output mode flags
  c_cflag resd 1   ; control mode flags
  c_lflag resd 1   ; local mode flags
  c_line  resb 1   ; line discipline
  c_cc    resb 19  ; control characters
```

Then get the current terminal settings and disable canonical mode:

```
; Get current settings
mov  eax, 16             ; syscall number: SYS_ioctl
mov  edi, 0              ; fd:      STDIN_FILENO
mov  esi, 0x5401         ; request: TCGETS
mov  rdx, termios        ; request data
syscall

; Modify flags
and byte [c_lflag], 0FDh  ; Clear ICANON to disable canonical mode

; Write termios structure back
mov  eax, 16             ; syscall number: SYS_ioctl
mov  edi, 0              ; fd:      STDIN_FILENO
mov  esi, 0x5402         ; request: TCSETS
mov  rdx, termios        ; request data
syscall
```

Now you can use `sys_read` to read in the keystroke:

```
mov  eax, 0              ; syscall number: SYS_read
mov  edi, 0              ; int    fd:  STDIN_FILENO
mov  rsi, buf            ; void*  buf
mov  rdx, len            ; size_t count
syscall
```

Afterwards check the return value in `rax`: It contains the number of characters read.

([Or a `-errno` code on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751614/what-are-the-return-values-of-system-calls-in-assembly), e.g. if you closed stdin by running `./a.out <&-` in bash.  Use `strace` to print a decoded trace of the system calls your program makes, so you don't need to actually write error handling in toy experiments.)

---

**References:**

- [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)
- [Why does the sys_read system call end when it detects a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194085/why-does-the-sys-read-system-call-end-when-it-detects-a-new-line)
- [How do i read single character input from keyboard using nasm (assembly) under ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305005/how-do-i-read-single-character-input-from-keyboard-using-nasm-assembly-under-u)
- [Using the raw keyboard mode under Linux](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/rawkb.html) (external site with example in 32-bit assembly)

Comment: so before i call the sys_read, i must setup sys_ioctl first ? and for the syscall are Int 80h? i'm new in assembly linux...  and the character i inputed are in RAX? and where i should put the write termios structure back? Btw thanks for the help... @fcdt

Comment: The `termios` structure is like a config file: You want to disable canonical mode, so you had to read in the current configuration, modify it, and write it back. I added a few lines about syscalls to the post.

Comment: Thanks @fcdt for the explanation... so the key i inputed are in RAX... okay then once again thanks

Comment: Be aware that some keys could lead to an input longer than just 1 byte so you have to call `sys_read` again in that cases. I've also found [this site](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/rawkb.html) about raw keyboard input in 32-bit linux assembly.

Comment: sorry for asking again @fcdt on the ```And byte [c_cflag], $FD``` i got a error when compiling ````key.asm:81: error: symbol `FD' undefined```` what the FD mean ?

Comment: Ups, using FASM normally. That should be `0FDh` or `0xFD` in NASM.

Comment: thanks @fcdt fixed already :), btw on termios struct NASM doesn't recognize rd and rb, but  recognize Resb or Resd

Comment: sorry for asking again @fcdt, the code are working but when i run it it is not read my keystroke its automatically input something.... eventually the code are jump to my error label for clear problem here my output: 
```nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs key.asm
ld -o KeyPress key.o
./KeyPress
Untuk memulai tekan tombol enter: 
Tekan tombol untuk memainkan satu not: (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Error note not found please contact the app developer !!```
I using make file to run it thanks for the help

Comment: That seems like a new question to me. Only from the output, I can not see what's going on there.

Comment: @fcdt Why do you enable `ICANON` in `c_cflag` instead of `c_lflag`? This link gives `ICANON` under `c_lflag` constants: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. `ICANON` is indeed a local flag.