# Assembly x86 Linux Not Reading User Input For One Specific Part

Tags: assembly, input, x86, x86-64, nasm

The initial syscall to read user input is working perfectly fine, but for some reason when I call for a second read later in the code, it doesn't work properly. It just terminates the program before letting the user input a value. I've placed comments where the two problem areas are in the code. Here is the code:

```
bits 64

global  _start

section .text
  _start: 
    ;Setting
    mov          rax, 1
    mov          rsi, unit
    mov          rdx, unitlen
    syscall

    mov          rax, 0
    mov          rsi, unitre ; assigns unitre in memory
    mov          rdx, 1
    syscall

    mov        al, [unitre] ; gets the value of the first character through pointing at unitre 
                            ; which is the first pointer of the string 
    cmp          al, 'q'
    je           exit

    cmp          al, 'c'
    je           _cels

    cmp          al, 'f'
    je           _fahr

    jmp exit

  _cels:
    mov          rax, 1
    mov          rdi, 1
    mov          rsi, numC
    mov          rdx, numClen
    syscall

    ; Problem area pt. 1
    mov          rax, 0
    mov          rdi, 1
    mov          rsi, numre
    mov          rdx, 1
    ;int 0x80

    jmp        _start
    ;convert numre to degrees fahrenheit
    mov          rax, [numre]
    imul         rax, 9
    mov          rbx, 5
    idiv         rbx
    add          rax, 32

    mov          rax, 1
    mov          rdi, 1
    mov          rsi, numre
    mov          rdx, numrelen
    syscall

    mov          rsi, deg
    mov          rdi, 1
    mov          rdx, degl
    syscall

    ;jmp        _start
  _fahr:
    mov          rax, 1
    mov          rdi, 1
    mov          rsi, numF
    mov          rdx, numFlen
    syscall

    ; Problem area pt. 2
    mov          rax, 0
    mov          rdi, 1
    mov          rsi, numre
    mov          rdx, numrelen
    syscall

    jmp        _start

    ; Convert numre to degrees celsius
    mov          rax, [numre]
    sub          rax, 32
    imul         rax, 5
    mov          rbx, 9
    idiv         rbx

    mov          rax, 1
    mov          rdi, 1
    mov          rsi, numre
    mov          rdx, numrelen
    syscall

    mov          rsi, deg
    mov          rdi, 1
    mov          rdx, degl
    syscall

    ;jmp         _start
  exit:
    ;Exits program
    mov          rax, 60
    xor          rdi, rdi
    syscall

section   .data
  ;Conversion
  unit:      db      "Unit ('c' for Celsius or 'f' for Fahrenheit): ", 10
  unitlen:      equ      $      -      unit
  unitre:      db      "", 10
  numC:      db      "Degrees(C): ", 10
  numClen:      equ      $      -      numC
  numF:      db      "Degrees(F): ", 10
  numFlen:      equ      $      -      numF
  numre:      db      "", 0
  numrelen:      equ      $      -      numre
  deg:        db        "degrees", 10
  degl:      equ      $      -      deg

  ;testing
  num1      db      1
```

I tried to have the user input a given temperature value to convert to either Celsius or Fahrenheit. The way I have it should work, but before even letting the user type the degrees (either C or F depending on what they put in initial prompt) the program just skips the syscall and moves back to the start (I placed "jmp _start" right after the read syscalls in '_fahr' and '_cels' in order to help debug).

Comment: Typing a letter and then pressing enter is two bytes of input, the second one being a newline.  Since your first  `read` syscall only reads 1 byte, the newline is still there in the kernel buffer for that TTY so your next 1-byte `read` reads it without having to wait.  So don't do that, use a bigger buffer that's long enough to consume whatever a user might type on the rest of a line, and the newline.  (This is still a "toy program" approach vs. scanning for newlines, e.g. if reading from a file one big read could be multiple lines.)

Comment: 32-bit mode near-duplicate: [How do I ignore line breaks in input using NASM Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18780927).  You're using `read` correctly via 64-bit `syscall`, don't use `int 0x80` in 64-bit code (*[What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)*).  The useful part of that line-break Q&A is the sizes of the read system calls, not the register usage details and the int 0x80.

Comment: Related: [Why does the sys\_read system call end when it detects a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39194085) Also,  [Basic input with x64 assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49925840) has working x86-64 code for reading 2 bytes, which would work for your case, and discussion about what happens with unread input.